# How can I make the command !say work with a user's id?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

This is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
 
module.exports = {
    name: 'say',
    description: 'say',
    execute(message, args){
        message.delete().catch(O_o => {});
        const { prefix, token } = require ('../config.json');
        
         const sayMessage = args.join(" ");
        message.delete().catch(O_o=>{}); 
        message.channel.send(sayMessage);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is make it work only with my id, and when someone tries to use this command it says "you are not my creator"

Comment: `O_o => {}` I like that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use an if statement to check the id

```js
if(message.author.id !== 'your id') {
  return message.channel.send('You are not my creator');
}
```